# C++ interrupt thread waiting for user-input

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I have a problem, where I need to interrupt and wait for input. Any idea how to do this?

```
bool run;
void partReceive() {
    while(run) {
        ...
        int rect_len = (int) recvfrom(servSockFD, buffer, 
              MAX_MESSAGE_LEN, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &newAddr, &slen);
        ...
    }
}

void partCount() {
    int i = 0;
    while(run) {
        i++;
        if (i >= 5) {
            run = false;
        }
    }
 }

 int main() {
       run = true;
       thread receive(partReceive);
       thread count(partCount);
       count.join();
       receive.join();
       return 0;
 }
```

This won't work, because partReceive() will hold until it receives input from socket..

Comment: How to do what?

Comment: I'd worry about `partCount`, because it has no connection to actual reception of parts to count them

Comment: Your use of `recvfrom()` implies a UDP socket is being used.  If so, then just set `run` to false and then `sendto()` a blank datagram to the listening socket port and let `partReceive()` receive it normally so it can then exit itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the [man page of recvfrom](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom):

You need to change receiver to first call `select` (see [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)) to check if there is something to read. If there is something to read you can `recvfrom` knowing that it now will not block. `select` can also timeout if nothing is to be read. In that case you can at least check if you shall end the receiver thread.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the existing answer, note that a useful design pattern is to use a pipe (or more precisely, a socketpair()), where main thread owns one end and the 'select thread' owns the other end. Then, to stop the 'select thread', you can send one character on the pipe (assuming the descriptor has been added to select). This wakes up the thread that should be terminated (thread sleeps in select until something happens on the socket or on the control pipe).